# Image loading is slow. Need to load only visible images

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview, loading

I am loading an image from memory into a `RecyclerView`. Not api call. From phone memory.
Each item in the `RecyclerView` has an image.
The images are loaded only when i scroll to them. Now the problem is, when i scroll fast to the 10th item, all 10 items are loading. When i view the 10th item, the 1-8 items are not visible in the device screen yet they are loading. How to prevent this. So when i see the 20th item, it is taking around 1 minute to load.
What I want is, load only visible images. When i scroll fast to the 20th item, load only the 20th item. 1-19 and 21-... should not load

Comment: Seems like LAYOUT issue . Use Constraint layout

Comment: Make images smaller... Or start loading after some time

Comment: 1 min seems much too long even when loading 20 images. Make sure to downsample huge images.

Comment: @Selvin - How will that work. Already it is slow. Loading after some time will delay it even more

Comment: @Henry - Your idea seems ok. I will try and get back here. Will see how to down sample the images

Comment: But you will be able to cancel it... You cant stop plain HTTP  onece you fired it up.. But with delay you can check if request is needed after some time and do not load

Comment: @Selvin I fear that will ruin the user experience. Expecting the user to cancel the loading is not a good idea.

Comment: More than 1 minute loading? Im talking about 1s(or even 0.5) delay... It should be enough to cancel fast scrolled  items

Comment: while I don't know exactly which code you have used to achieve this, I will suggest you to use glide or picasso for image loading in android. https://square.github.io/picasso/ or  https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: It all depends on the code you use to place the images. And as you did not post that code there is not much to say. It looks as if you dont use lazy loading...

Answer (score 0):

Try not to load the image in original size in RecyclerView. This severely ***freezes*** the UI.

It is better to use **thumbnail** images to display in recycleview.

Consider the following example:

[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

```kotlin
Glide.with(context).load(image_file).thumbnail().into(imageView)
```